# Set enum value by other value of the enum

Tags: java, enums

I want a method to obtain the second value using the first value as parameter. 
To place this exercise in context, Nota is mark (in spanish) and the second values would be the grading standards used here (instead of F, D-, D, C....)

As you can see, the grading standards got repeated while the int numbers. (Yes, this exercise should be made with floats, but ignore it), so the int value (numNota) would be like an identifier.

```
public enum Nota {
NOTA0(0,"Suspenso"),
NOTA1(1,"Suspenso"),
NOTA2(2,"Suspenso"),
NOTA3(3,"Suspenso"),
NOTA4(4,"Suspenso"),
NOTA5(5,"Suficiente"),
NOTA6(6,"Bien"),
NOTA7(7,"Notable"),
NOTA8(8,"Notable"),
NOTA9(9,"Sobresaliente"),
NOTA10(10,"Sobresaliente");

private int numNota;
private String stringNota;

Nota(int numNota, String stringNota) {
  this.numNota = numNota;
  this.stringNota = stringNota;
}

public int getNumNota() {
    return numNota;
}

public String getStringNota() {
    return stringNota;
}

public void setByNumNota(int numNota) {
    this.numNota = numNota;
    this.stringNota = ?????????
}
```

I'm assigning each nota (mark) to an alumn

```
public Alumno(String nombre, Nota nota) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.nota = nota;
}
```

And the mark is being introduced by input scanner. That's why I need to create a Nota object from the int value of mark.

This exercise is without database yet. Our classes are full java now, all the data loads in memory for now (I wish we were using DB already lol)

Comment: If `stringNota` is completely dependent on `numNota`, then you don't need to have it as a constructor parameter

Comment: This tends to lean towards bad design, but you can forward reference using a `Supplier<Enum>`, as long as you ensure you don't call it before the rest of the enum initializes

Comment: A better design in a production-esque environment would be to externalize data like this and load it from a file or database

Comment: @user I've also thought and tried that that, but... when I remove stringNota from the constructor, the values will go in error "The constructor Nota(int,String) is undefined"

Comment: Then you just define your enum values as `NOTA0(0), NOTA1(1)`, etc. and calculate the value of `stringNota` inside the constructor, possibly with a switch

Comment: Can you state your goal more clearly?  I'm not able to precisely understand the problem that you need to solve.

Comment: I know I could make this with a switch, but... I want to avoid to repeat case 0, case 1...... case 10. I was wondering if there was a shorter and more dynamic way of obtain this.

Comment: @scottb Look at the last method of public enum Nota, I want to obtain the value of stringNota, using numNota as parameter

Comment: Why do you want to (re)set the values of an enum?

Comment: @Sandrituky: Enums are intended to represent a fixed set of constants, all of whose attributes are known at compile time (eg. the planets in the solar system, or the months of the year).  What I hear you saying is that you want to dynamically set attributes of enums at run time.  This defeats the intent of the enum facility and is not directly supported by the language.  It does not sound like you should be using enums to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since `stringNota` can be determined from `numNota` (but not the other way around), it doesn't have to be a constructor parameter. You can simply compute it inside the constructor and only have the number as a parameter.

```
public enum Nota {
NOTA0(0),
NOTA1(1),
NOTA2(2),
NOTA3(3),
NOTA4(4),
NOTA5(5),
NOTA6(6),
NOTA7(7),
NOTA8(8),
NOTA9(9),
NOTA10(10);

private int numNota;
private String stringNota;

Nota(int numNota) {
  this.numNota = numNota;
  stringNota = stringFromNumNota(numNota); //see below
}
```

There's no need to check for negative numbers and numbers above 10 because the constructor is effectively private.

**EDIT**: To get `stringNota` from `numNota`, you can just write an extra method.

```
public String stringFromNumNota(int numNota) {
  return numNota < 5 ? "Suspenso"
    : numNota == 5 ? "Suficiente"
    : numNota == 6 ? "Bien"
    : numNota < 9 ? "Notable"
    : "Sobresaliente";
}
```

Comment: It's a nice solution, but... this question was made not with the goal of get the solution. I made it with the goal of trying (maybe this is not possible) to:
**Get one value of enum using the other value of enum.**
I want to know if it's possible do that, and how, if possible.

Comment: @Sandrituky I've edited my answer. Is that satisfactory?